# Summation of infinite series, where difference in consecutive denominator forms an A.P.

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

What is the sum of an infinite series where

1. each term can be written as $\frac{p}{q}$, where p=1 always
2. the difference between 2 consecutive denominators forms an A.P.

For example
$\dfrac{1}{2}$, $\dfrac{1}{6}$, $\dfrac{1}{12}$, $\dfrac{1}{20}$, $\dfrac{1}{30}$ ......

Here,

$6-2=4$
$12-6=6$
$20-12=8$
$30-20=10$
.
.
.
.
.

where, 4,6,8,10....
form an arithmetic progression

Note: I would prefer if this question be answered using only elementary math,  however, other solutions would also be appreciated. I have no knowledge of using limits

Comment: Elementary math doesn't work here. Look at series $\sum 1/n^2 = \pi^2/6$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Your denominators 
$$
2,6,12,20,30,\ldots
$$ are such that
$$
d_{n+1}-d_n=2(n+1),\quad d_1=2, \quad n=1,2,3,\cdots,
$$ giving, by telescoping,
$$
d_n=n(n+1), \quad n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$ Thus your series (a telescoping one) rewrites

> $$
> \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n(n+1)}=\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)=\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(1-\frac1{N+1}\right)=\color{red}{1}.
> $$

Comment: The question specifies "for example".

Comment: @Did Ok, I did not properly read it. I will leave someone give a general answer. The elementary tool is the same :) This is really a hint. Thanks!

Comment: "The elementary tool is the same " Actually no, not in general.

Comment: @Did Oh, interesting, thanks!